# Apache Maven - Downgrading to previous snapshot dependency version is not working

Tags: maven, jenkins, artifactory

I have a maven project which is injected with a SNAPSHOT dependency 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT which is there in artifactory. Now dependency project's pom version is updated to 2.0.1-SNAPSHOT and it was built  (from a jenkins job) and this snapshot is also there in artifactory. So now artifactory has both the versions 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT and 2.0.1-SNAPSHOT and on local m2 repository also both versions are there.

Main project updated the SNAPSHOT dependency to 2.0.1-SNAPSHOT and it is able to see the new changes in 2.0.1-SNAPSHOT.

Now code changes are made in 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT and it was build and updated in artifactory but now when main project reverted back to 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT and built with -U (force update snapshots), it is not able to see new change done in 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.

Can anyone suggest what could be wrong here ?

Comment: Why is there a revert back of the version? Furthermore do the 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT even exist in artifactory and have not being deleted (which is a the usual approache after a 2.0.0 release...)..

Comment: Yes it exists in artifactory along with other older snapshot versions.

Comment: Ok..first thing is wrong not to delete old snapshots because there is a release (2.0.0 release and all 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT's can be removed). But the question keeps. Why is there a version revert back? from 2.0.1 to 2.0.0 that does not make sense? Can you please explain why this happens?

Comment: BTw: Have you checked if the 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT has been rebuilt ...correct...

Comment: There is no 2.0.0 release yet. We are doing it because we want to do a hot fix release  from a git tag and we updated pom version to 2.0.1-SNAPSHOT so that hotfix changes does not overlab with 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT which has latest dev changes. And yes 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT has been rebuilt correctly, we downloaded jar and decompiled it to verify new changes.

Comment: Any x.y.z-SNAPSHOT will only ever resolve the latest SNAPSHOT. There will only be one (latest) local copy. The remote MAY have several copies, but will only ever survive the latest. You would have to manipulate the remote to delete the entire set(pom+jar) and Re-index to maybe get prior timestamped upload. Might be easier to undo the commit or jump it and rebuild. You are ki d of violating the motivation of -SHAPSHOTs